# MongoDB docker-compose container throught traefik with TLS

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm trying to open a MongoDB container with docker-compose while having a reverse-proxy,
Traefik, to have TLS.

Here is my configuration:

docker-compose.yml:

```
networks:
  frontend:
    external: true

services:

  mongo:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    #ports:
    # - 27017:27017
    expose:
      - 27017
    networks:
     - mongodb
    volumes:
     - ./dbdata:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    labels:
        - 'traefik.enable=true'
        - 'traefik.tcp.routers.mongodb.rule=HostSNI(`sub.domain.com`)'
        - 'traefik.tcp.routers.mongodb.entrypoints=mongo'
        - 'traefik.tcp.routers.mongodb.tls=true'
        - "traefik.tcp.routers.mongodb.tls.certresolver=production"
        - 'traefik.tcp.services.mongodb.loadbalancer.server.port=27017'
```

The traefik config for the entrypoint is here:
traefik.yml:

```
entryPoints:
  mongo:
    address: :27017
```

There is no problem in the traefik log, and nothing out of normal in the mongodb container's log neither.

The TCP route of the mongo container does appear in the traefik dashboard.

My problem is while connecting with MongoDB Compass, the connection is refused
`connect ECONNREFUSED ipv4:27017`
And this happens using SSL/TLS true and default with the following connection string:
`mongodb://username:password@sub.domain.com/?authMechanism=DEFAULT&authSource=db_name&tls=true`
Again the &tls=true part does not solve the issue.

Can someone explain to me what I'm missing ?

I did research the subject but had no luck with what I tried.

I saw this [How to setup mongodb with traefik and docker compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71300670/how-to-setup-mongodb-with-traefik-and-docker-compose)

And researched for enabling tls on the mongodb container, however I'm not sure what to do in order to not have multiple certs (beside the traefik one) nor having self-signed cert.

I also tried to adapt this [Is it possible to use Traefik to proxy PostgreSQL over SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63354909/is-it-possible-to-use-traefik-to-proxy-postgresql-over-ssl)

But with no luck.

Comment: Usually you need to provide a server certificate in MongoDB config when you like to use TLS/SSL. But I don't see any in your configuration.

Comment: Did you check the `mongod` logfile? Usually at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I checked inside /var/log/mongodb in the container but there is no file inside it. For the cert of Mongo, is there no other solution ? I would like to let traefik manage it and leave mongo behind a reverse-proxy.

Comment: No idea, I am not familiar with containers

Comment: Did you get this to work? I have the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I used a local MongoDB database for development purposes, and another that would be in the same network as my docker container using it for production. This way it doesn't even need the SSL certs. Even if it's solving my initial problem, it doesn't answer the question.